# Find P(C) - Mutually Exclusive Events and Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Events $A, B, C$ are such that $B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive and $P(A) = 2/3, P(A \cup B) = 5/6$ and
$P(B \cup C) = 4/5$. If $P(B|A) = 1/2$ and $P(C|A) = 3/10$, calculate $P(C)$.

Comment: Welcome to the website! Please edit your question and give us more context. Add what you have tried and where you are stuck. You may use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations in future (I have done it for you this time).

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. I need to find P(C) but I'm not sure how. My first question i have is, if events B and C are mutually exclusive, does that mean that A and B, and events A and C are mutually exclusive? (i.e. are A and C statistically independent?

Comment: Yes you need $P(B)$. Since only $P(A)$ is known, try playing around with $P(B|A)$ and $P(A\cup B)$

Comment: No, $A,C$ or $A,B$ need not be be disjoint in general. And in this question, they are clearly not disjoint since $P(C|A),P(B|A)\ne0$

Comment: could you walk me through it, i'm not sure how to find p(C)

Answer (score 1):

You correctly guessed that we need $P(B)$ first. Since $P(A)$ is known, we should look for relations between $A,B$.

They are $P(A\cup B)=5/6,P(B|A)=1/2$.

By definition$P(B|A)=P(A\cap B)/P(A)$ which gives $P(A\cap B)=\frac12\times P(A)=1/3$.

We know $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=5/6$ using which find $P(B)$.

Finally $P(B\cup C)=P(B)+P(C)$ since $P(B\cap C)=0,$ using which find $P(C)$.

Comment: Could you please confirm what p(B) is? I got 0.5 but that doesn't seem right?

Comment: @Anon Why doesn't it seem right? It is correct.

Comment: Oh, so in that case, if the p(b) is 0.5, C then would be also be 0.5? I was confused because events B and C are mutually exclusive so I thought this meant P(B or C) cannot equal 0? Or is that wrong?

Comment: @Anon Well, $P(C)=P(B\cup C)-P(B)=4/5-1/2=3/10$.

Comment: Can A and C be statistically independent?

Comment: @Anon You need to see whether $P(A)\times P(C)=P(A\wedge C)$. RHS can be found by using the expression $P(A\wedge C)=P(C|A)P(A)$. Are the two values equal?